# class in ruby(declaration of class in ruby)

Tags: ruby

Is this statement enough in Ruby to create a class?

```
demo = Amiy.new
```

Will it create a class named Amiy in Ruby?

Answer (score 11):

No. What this code does is create an instance (object) of the `Amiy` class. To create a class you use the `class` statement:

```
class Amiy
  # ...
end
```

Once you've created the class then you can make an instance of it:

```
my_object = Amiy.new
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to declare a new class, you should do as Jordan said and use this syntax:

```
class Amiy
end
```

But technically you can do something like this:

```
Amiy = Class.new
puts "Amiy: #{(Amiy).inspect}"

instance = Amiy.new
puts "instance: #{(instance).inspect}"
```

Running that will give you something like this:

```
Amiy: Amiy
instance: #<Amiy:0xb7500b24>
```